# VB .NET Xml tags raise a warning

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

For example:

```
''' <img runat="server" src="<%$ Theme: Images/Salva.gif %>" />
Public Class MyClass
...
End Class
```

The commented XML row raises several warnings, for example:

- XML documentation parse error: Character '%' (&H25) is not allowed at the beginning of an XML name. XML comment will be ignored.

How can I make this comment correct to avoid raising warnings?

Comment: A regular comment in VB.NET introduced by a single `'`. Using three of them is the [syntax for XML documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172652.aspx), I think you did not intend to use that.

Comment: True, thanks. I was also wondering if is it possible to escape those not allowed characters

Comment: There is nothing to escape, just don't use `'''` when you don't mean to write XML documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the text in XML comment could change it to use character data. That would get rid of the warnings, but would depend on how the image tag was going to be used.

```
''' <![CDATA[<img runat="server" src="<%$ Theme: Images/Salva.gif %>" />]]>
Public Class MyClass
...
End Class
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA